# '=' and '-' characters single quotation

Tags: punctuation

I have a problem getting the **-** and **=** characters between single quotations.

`` `-' `` and `` `=' `` both produces `-'` in the generated pdf. If I put an alphabetical character between `` ` `` and `'` it works as expected. I guess `-` and `=` are special characters.

How do I treat them?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min}

\usepackage{t1enc} 

\usepackage{times} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

Hello TeX! This is how I try to add single quotation marks before and after the characters `-' and `='.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that `t1enc` and `times` are obsolete. Rather use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and, for Times, `\usepackage{mathptmx}` or `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}).

Comment: some "duplicate" packages here: `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so no need to have them both.  also, `mathtools` loads `amsmath`.  and the usual recommendation is that `hyperref` should be loaded last; for this, you should check specific package recommendations, because there *are* some exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file `magyar.ldf` defines `` ` `` as a shorthand prefix; in particular, from what I have been able to understand from the code,

```
`--
```

gives an “intelligent en-dash”; when `` `- `` appears, it just produces a hyphen. Conversely, `` `= `` is a hyphen for composite words, allowing hyphenation in the word part following the hyphen.

If you want a single opening quote, just type `` `{} ``

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}

Hello TeX! This is how I try to add single quotation marks
before and after the characters `{}-' and `{}='.

Examples:

\verb|$a-b$|: $a-b$

\verb|$a`--b$|: $a`--b$

\verb|a-b|: a-b

\verb|a`-b|: a`-b

\verb|a`--b|: a`--b
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the language definition file is rather poorly documented. In the sense that I couldn't find any documentation for it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Tried `csquotes`? It has commands like:

1. \textquoteleft
2. and \textquoteright

And an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}

\newcommand\singlequote[1]{\textquoteleft #1\textquoteright~}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\singlequote{=} some text here. \\
\singlequote{-} more text here.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works nicely. I have text right after the quotation, but no spaces were added after the \textquoteright command. I added ~ after it to force a space.

Comment: I've edited my post slightly so you can use a macro instead of typing it all out every single time.

Comment: Having loaded `csquotes` this way you can just write `\enquote*{=}` etc.